# how can i debug the opening of my application from a file on OSX?

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging

I linked my application to a file extension, so when i double click those files it opens my application. However i experience crash when doing so, and i am looking for a way to breakpoint that and see what's going wrong. I'm using Xcode, it's an OSX app.

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe you can link your file extension to: `lldb -- /your/exec/goes/here --your --exec --args --go --here`

Comment: this will probably not open the debugger when opening the debug app, am i right?

Comment: Does the app crash if it's already running when the file is opened by double click?

Comment: it does not crash when the app is already running

Answer (score 4):

lldb doesn't have a "launch with open AppleEvent" feature, so you can't do this directly.

But you can use lldb's "attach wait" feature to catch the app early in startup.  You can do this in Xcode by turning on "Wait for the executable to be launched" in the Info tab of the Run scheme of your App target.  Then click the Run button, and go to Finder to launch your app by double-clicking on one of its files.

If your system is not heavily loaded, lldb will generally stop the app pretty early in its startup, usually before it gets to handling the open event.  Xcode will auto-continue the app, so it should just proceed right to the crash.

If for some reason lldb doesn't attach early enough, edit the main function of your application, and at the very top put in:

```
int go_on = 0;
while(!go_on) {
  sleep(1);
}
```

That way your app will stall in launching before it handles the open event, giving 
lldb time to attach.  Once it has attached, Pause the app in the debugger, select the thread and frame containing this main function, go to the lldb Console and do:

```
(lldb) expr go_on = 1
```

and then continue.  Now your app should finish starting up, handle the open event and crash into the debugger.

Comment: I usually make the `go_on` variable `volatile`, just to be sure the compiler doesn't optimize it away. I guess it probably isn't likely to for a debug build, but still.

Comment: Passing it to printf is another pretty sure way to keep it alive, particularly if you do `printf("%p\n", &go_on)` since then the compiler can't tell at all what you meant to do with it.  But it's been a long time since I've had a compiler that's that over-aggressive at -O0.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement of Jim's answer: If your application is responding to the `kAEOpenDocuments` event through

```objectivec
- (void)handleAppleEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)event
          withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)replyEvent
```

you can debug your application using Xcode as usual, and set a breakpoint on the line where you start to process that event (or at the beginning if it crashing before reaching that point). Once set up, go to Finder and open the file.

Take into account that when double-clicking it will launch the default app, so if your debug build is not the default one you have to choose "Open With > Other...".